# Why does my Short containing 4 bytes in VB.net

Tags: .net, vb.net, short

According to MSDN a `Short` datatype consists of two bytes: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/47zceaw7.aspx

But if I define a `Short` variable, the content is always 4 bytes: &HFFFFFFFF

```
Dim crc As Short = CShort(&HFFFFS) ' crc = &HFFFFFFFF
Dim crc As Short = &HFFFFS         ' crc = &HFFFFFFFF
```

And this statement even gives me an error:

```
Dim crc As Short = CShort(&HFFFF) ' Error: Constant expression not representable in type 'Short'
```

What's the deal with this? Why does my `Short` doesn't take two bytes?

**MWE added:**

```
Public Function CRC16(ByVal dataFrame As Byte(), ByVal dataLength As Int16) As Int16

    Dim index As Int16
    Dim crc As Short = &HFFFFS

    For iCount As Int16 = 0 To CShort(dataLength - 1)
        index = (crc >> 8) Xor dataFrame(iCount)
        crc = CShort(&HFFFF And ((crc << 8) Xor CRC_Table(index)))
    Next

    Return crc

End Function
```

Comment: Your error statement doesn't surprise me seeing as a *signed* `Short` can only hold up to 32,767 - so `&HFFFF` is too big. Can you show a piece of executable code that shows your issue? How do you know the content at this point is 4 bytes?

Comment: @Farhan Thanks, that was my error in reasoning, my intension is to set all bits to 1 and not pass the value of &HFFFF how can I do this?

Comment: @Macro The "Mouse over variable" function and Watch window in VS showed me the value.

Comment: It is just a debugger artifact, happens when you tick "Hexadecimal Display" in the context menu.  Yes, it certainly does not win any prizes but it isn't dramatically wrong, it is still -1 when you assign a Short to an Integer.

Comment: If I assign `&HFFFFS` to a `Short` I get a return value of `-1` as Hans eluded to above, which would support his comment.

Comment: Anyway, for CRC16 why don't you just use unsigned short instead? That will solve the whole issue...

Comment: @Ian Thanks for the hint, I wasn't aware of the existenece of unsigned datatypes in VB

Comment: @Raphael ah yes, you could simply change all your `Short` to `UShort`, `CShort` to `CUShort` and all is done. ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is because a `Short` is **signed**, so the most significant bit is reserved for the sign. Therefore the highest value you can store in a *signed* short is `&H7FFF` or [`Int16.MaxValue`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int16.maxvalue(v=vs.110).aspx)

If you want to utilise all 16 bits then you need to use an **Unsigned** Short (`UInt16`)

So this Fails:

```
Dim crc As Short = CShort(&HFFFF)
```

But this Works:

```
Dim crc As UShort = CUShort(&HFFFF)
```